# Is it possible to upgrade Windows without affecting Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, upgrade, 13.10, windows-8

I have Ubuntu 13.10 and Windows 7 installed on my computer. Even if most of the time I use  Ubuntu, I would like to upgrade win7 to win8.1 (as student I have it free).

I'm wondering if the installation of Windows does not work without touching the dual boot or the ubuntu partition or ubuntu configuration.

Can I go on without be worry?

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  If you have installed Ubuntu and Windows in UFEI mode, my guess is that everything should be fine.  However if your boot loader is stored on an MBR Windows will definitely overwrite Grub.

In either case, it's best to just make a boot-repair-disk that will automagically fix grub.  Boot-Repair-Disk and instructions on how to use it can be found here:
http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/

Comment: how can I understand if it's UFEI or MBR?

Comment: Your boot set-up (BIOS) settings is the proper place to check.  However if partition manager, click on your drive; if the first partition is mounted at /boot/efi then you likely are using ufei.